# Find and remove a Python object from locals() or globals()

Tags: python, python-2.7, telnetlib

I'm using `telnetlib` to communicate with some equipment which has Telnet implemented as single user.
Therefore, I have to detect and remove the telnet object created from a previous attempt to establish communication.(Ex: `tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)`)
My attempt is something like bellow but it does not work:

```
 if 'tn' in loccals() or 'tn' in globals():
     print "Telnet object exists. Remove it."
     tn.close()
     del tn
 else:
     print "Create a Telnet object."
     global tn
     tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

print tn
```

Comment: Why test both locals and globals? You make it clear `tn` is a global with the `global tn` line. And define *does not work*? Why not just rebind `tn` to `None` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't delete, rebind. Start with `tn` set to `None`:

```
tn = None
```

Now you can test for the value:

```
if tn is not None:
    tn.close()
    tn = None
else:
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
```

Note that the `global` keyword marks a name as global *in the whole scope*, not just from that line onwards.

Comment: 1. Sounds good but if we have `tn=None`, the script will never exectute `tn.close()`. 2. What line should be `global tn`?

Comment: @flamenco: if `tn` is `None`, there is *nothing **to** close*. It doesn't matter what line `global tn` is on; it applies to the whole function it is in. As such it makes sense to list it first, for readability.